# Using eventListeners with objects in HTML5 Canvas (Not Able to get object properties in functions)

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5-canvas

I've been trying to draw 3 rectangles each right below one another using object in javascript and canvas and add an event listener to them. When one of the rectangles is hovered over, I want the rectangles to move over to the right 50 pixels, and then when the mouse hovers off a rectangle, it moves back to its original position.

So far I have created the object, declared the eventListeners, and have been able to get the mouse coordinates.

However, I can't seem to use the objects properties within the function that is called inside the eventListener. The properties show up as undefined in the JavaScript console. I am not sure how to use the properties for the rectangles I have created. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
// coordinates for the canvas start at the top left of the canvas object
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
// get the 2D context object of the document
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");



class Rectangle {
    constructor(xpos, ypos, width, height, color){
        this.x = xpos;
        this.y = ypos;
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.color = color;
    }

    draw(ctx){
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);

        // adding the text
        ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    }

    mouseHoveredOn() {
        let mx = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        let my = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        if( (mx >= this.x && mx <= (this.x + this.width) ) && (my >= this.y && my <= (this.y + this.height)) ){
            for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
                ctx.clearRect(30+i, 150, 170, 60);
                ctx.fillRect(31+i, 150, 170, 60);
            }
        }
    }

    mouseHoveredOff() {
        let mx = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
        let my = event.clientY - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        if( (mx <= this.x || mx >= (this.x + this.width) ) || (my <= this.y || my >= (this.y + this.height)) ) {
            for(let i = 50; i > 0; i--) {
                ctx.clearRect(31+i, 150, 170, 60);
                ctx.fillRect(30+i, 150, 170, 60);
            }
        }
    }

}




let rect1 = new Rectangle(30, 150, 170, 60, "rgb(200, 0, 200)"); 
rect1.draw(ctx);

let rect2 = new Rectangle(30, 230, 170, 60, "rgb(200, 0, 200)"); 
rect2.draw(ctx);

let rect3 = new Rectangle(30, 310, 170, 60, "rgb(200, 0, 200)"); 
rect3.draw(ctx);


canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', rect1.mouseHoveredOn, false);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', rect1.mouseHoveredOff, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

`addEventListener` is binding the `this` context for your class method to the target object and therefore replacing the expected Rectangle object. Because of this `this.x` and `this.y` are `undefined` and `this.width` and `this.height` reflect the canvas element's dimensions.

To get around this, you need to ensure your class method is bound with the correct context. For instance, you could create a separate function that calls the method, like:

```
class Rect {
  ...

  mouseHoveredOn(event) {
    let mx = event.clientX - canvas.getBoundingClientRect().left;
  ...

  }
}


const handleOn = (event) => {
  rect1.mouseHoveredOn(event)
}

canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', handleOn, false);
```